# iOS change Enterprise Account for existing App

Tags: ios, ios-enterprise, iosdeployment

I would like to know if its also possible to transfer an existing app from one Enterprise Developer Account. For example:

We already deployed an app with an existing account and specific app id: com.company.appname

Now i would like to transfer that app (app identifier) to another Enterprise account. Is that possible?

I already know how to migrate apps through developer accounts through iTunesConnect, but how does this work with enterprise apps? Is it allowed to create the "same" app identifier on 2 different accounts? What happens when ill update the app with all the data? The same identifier should only update the existing app, and not install a new one.

How does this work?

Edit: i´ve tried now something new:

1. use iExplorer to copy all Data from existing App to your Mac
2. install app with new identifier and new programm
3. copy all files back to new app, delete the "old" app.

Its about 10 Installations where i want to use the "new" development Programm. Maybe ill just copy all files manually, because in this case ill know that everything works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]Yes, you can migrate.

When you migrate your app to other enterprise account, then you will lost your app identifier from your account. When you will update the app from enterprise account, you will see an update of that application, not a new app. From your account, you won't be able to update or make a new app with the same identifier.

Please Note : This is screenshot from a developer account and i'm not sure about enterprise account portal. It should work like developer account too.

Comment: So just to be sure, because your answer is a bit unclear to me. Do i need to "delete" the existing app identifier in the "old" programm?

Comment: No, you don't need to delete the app from old membership. When you transfer your app to other account, it will transfer the identifier to that account too.

Comment: how do i transfer an app? Its an enterprise account, not a default developer account (where i can use iTunesConnect to transfer)

Comment: You can see from screenshot. Choose Transfer App.

Comment: The question is about apps on Enterprise accounts, not about ones in the App Store. There is not portal for these. I suspect the answer to the question is "no" but I cannot test it out.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can transfer your app from one account to another account.

You may not need to delete existing app from your account. There is an app transition process in apple developer account, which moves your app from your account to another account.

> **Answer to your question: When try to deploy it with another account again it says me "app identifier unavailable, already used" -
>   so any ideas how to solve this task with enterprise deployment? Or can
>   i migrate business apps to itunesConnect?**
>
> **Recommended Solution:**
>   You don't need to remove your app or bundle identifier from your account. You can convert business app into public app by updating certificates and provisioning profiles associated with your app. Then you can process for app transfer between two accounts.
>
> **Another Solution:**
>   Delete your app from your developer account (along with bundle identifier) and then create a new app with same identifier in another account, to which you want an app tranfer

Here is an apple guideline for the same:

[Transferring and Deleting Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html)

> You move apps out of your organization’s catalog of apps by
>   transferring an app to another organization or by deleting the app.
>   You want to transfer an app when you’ve sold the app to another
>   developer or you want to move it to another iTunes Connect
>   organization. You want to delete an app when you’re ready to retire an
>   app and there’s no chance you will want to offer it for sale or
>   download in the future or to reuse the app name.
>
> You can transfer the ownership of an app to another developer without
>   removing the app from the store. The app retains its reviews and
>   ratings during and after the transfer, and users continue to have
>   access to future updates. There’s no limit to the number of apps you
>   can transfer, but each app needs to be transferred individually.
>
> All transfers and deletions are performed by the team agent.

**Transferring an App**

You’ll need the team agent for the receiving organization to provide the team agent’s Apple ID and Team ID. Recipients can find their Team ID in their account at developer.apple.com.

The team agent is the only one who can transfer an app.

**To initiate an app transfer**

1. Make a record of app information you want to have after the transfer.

   Because you won’t be able to view the app information after the transfer, make a catalog report (see Requesting Catalog Reports), note dates the app was available on the store (see Viewing Status History), and save sales and download information (see Viewing Sales and Trends).
2. Open the App Details page for the app, as described in Creating an iTunes Connect Record for an App.
3. In the App Information section under App Store, scroll to the Additional Information section and click Transfer App.

[image]

4. Make sure the app meets the criteria for transferring.

   - If all criteria have been met, click Done.

   - If all criteria haven’t been met, resolve those that are outstanding.
5. Enter the recipient’s Team Agent Apple ID and Team ID, and click Continue.

[image]

6. Verify the transfer information and contract terms.
7. Read the contract terms, select “I have read and agree to the agreement presented above,” and click Request Transfer.

[image]

8. Click Done to return to the App Details page.

Once the transfer has been initiated and is awaiting acceptance by the recipient, the app stays in its previous status, with the Pending App Transfer status added. You can change the price of the app during this time.

The transfer must be accepted by the recipient organization’s Team Agent within 60 days.

**To accept an app transfer**

1. Sign in to iTunes Connect as the Team Agent.

   A notice appears indicating that an app is ready to be transferred.

[image]

2. Click Agreements, Tax and Banking.
3. In the Transfer Agreements section, locate the app being transferred in the Contracts In Process subsection and click Review.

[image]

4. Enter the new metadata and review it.

   - Support URL

   - Atom feed URL (required if the app previously had an atom feed URL entered)

   - Marketing URL (required if the app previously had a marketing URL entered)

   - Privacy policy URL (required if the app previously had a privacy policy URL entered)

   - CCATS (a new CCATS form is required for apps that use export compliance)

   - App Review contact information

   - App Store contact information
5. Read the contract terms, and select “I have read and agree to the agreement presented above,” and click Accept.

It can take up to two business days for the app transfer to complete, during which the app status is listed as Processing App Transfer. While the app is in the transfer state, the following actions apply:

- All app metadata, rights, and pricing are locked down on the transferor side and no in-app purchase edits can be made.
- Any open communications on the Resolution Center page are closed out.
  If the app is part of a Game Center group, no changes can be made to the group on the recipient side.
- After the transfer is complete, the app is now owned by the app transfer recipient. It no longer appears in the the transferor’s iTunes Connect account.

> **Important:**  The exchange of the actual code set and build assets takes
>   place directly between the transferor and recipient. App IDs are
>   transferred automatically in developer.apple.com. To maintain a great
>   user experience, inform the recipient about any capabilities added to
>   the app, such as keychain sharing or push notifications, so that the
>   recipient maintains these capabilities in future updates. Keychain
>   sharing continues to work until the app is updated, after which point,
>   prior keychain data cannot be accessed. If the keychain group is
>   defined in the Xcode project, it must be replaced with a keychain
>   group created by the recipient (that includes the recipient's Team ID)
>   for the app to continue using keychain sharing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, the app is not i iTunesConnect (its a business app with inhouse deployment) - that why ill ask for the enterprise programm. When ill now try to deploy it with another account again it says me "app identifier unavailable, already used" - so any ideas how to solve this task with enterprise deployment? Or can i migrate business apps to itunesConnect? (because normally as i know the business accounts are unable to use iTunesConnect)

Comment: Answer to your question:
Recommended Solution: You don't need to remove your app or bundle identifier from your account. You can convert business app into public app by updating certificates and provisioning profiles associated with your app. Then you can process for app transfer between two accounts.

Comment: Another Solution: Delete your app from your developer account (along with bundle identifier) and then create a new app with same identifier in another account, to which you want an app tranfer

Comment: Yes thats something i could try out (but first want to ask, because not sure if its working (maybe the app identifier is "blocked" after deleting) - and then i am unable to update the existing app with the old account too ;)

Comment: I have got a similar kind of question, but for me I don't want to use iTunes connect. The app which I want to transfer is currently an in-House Enterprise App and I want to transfer this to a different Enterprise  in-house license without changing the bundle id.

Comment: @Anand - In-house (enterprise) apps are standalone apps, Just delete it from your account and handover to next enterprise.